# Cralwer not creating table in data lake from postgres partition table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-data-pipeline, aws-lake-formation

My Table is partitioned in postgres. I have created a Glue crawler to create table.  I selected the option "Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table" in Configure the crawler's output. Since it's partitioned, the table is not created. Can you please suggest the option to create table in glue.

```
 CREATE TABLE book (
   ID int8 NULL,
   effectivetodate date NULL,
 ) PARTITION BY LIST (effectivetodate);
```